# AOS - Animate on scroll library (Problem with few divs on my website)

Tags: javascript, animation

First of all, this script works fine for some of my elements on page. But, for example on footer it wont work unless i zoom in/out page, then it triggers animation. Does anyone have a clue how this could be fixed.

[AOS - github.io](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) This is a Library im using.

And for all elements i used same code:

```
data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300" data-aos-offset="0"
```

I thought it has something to do with my css, but i didn't found anything that would help me fixed it. Also i tryed different **offsets**, **delay** and **animations**. None of this helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Can you share your code or a simple example? The fact that you mention "footer" makes me think that the footer is never reaching the screen position for the animation to start

Comment: Have you tried using `data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom"`? This would mean the footer would animate when the 'top' of it is aligned with the 'bottom' of the screen. If this is too early you could try `data-aos-anchor-placement="center-bottom"`